# I try to register BGTaskScheduler.shared.register but return error

Tags: ios, swift

I try to register BGTaskScheduler.shared.register but return error.
I build app video call and I try BGTaskScheduler for get incoming call from server. But I get error *** Assertion failure in -[BGTaskScheduler.

console error log

```
2021-07-16 16:56:19.567856+0700 Noble Zoom[67044:9082256] *** Assertion failure in -[BGTaskScheduler _unsafe_registerForTaskWithIdentifier:usingQueue:launchHandler:], BGTaskScheduler.m:181
2021-07-16 16:56:19.568033+0700 Noble Zoom[67044:9082256] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Launch handlers cannot be registered in extensions'
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import BackgroundTasks

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
        var window: UIWindow?
        let callManager = CallManager()
        var providerDelegate: ProviderDelegate!

        class var shared: AppDelegate {
            return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        }

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            
            providerDelegate = ProviderDelegate(callManager: callManager)
            registerBackgroundFetch()
            return true
        }
    
    private func registerBackgroundFetch() {
        let backgroundTaskID = "app.Nvideocall.BackgroundAppRefresh"
      // This code registers your background fetch task.
      BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: backgroundTaskID, using: nil) { task in
        // You must set an expiration handler that calls `task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)`
        task.expirationHandler = {
          print("Task expired")
          task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
        }
            print("Refreshing app in background. Time remaining: \(UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining) s")
        
        }
      }
    
    
    


        func displayIncomingCall(
            uuid: UUID,
            handle: String,
            hasVideo: Bool = false,
            completion: ((Error?) -> Void)?
        ) {
        providerDelegate.reportIncomingCall(
          uuid: uuid,
          handle: handle,
          hasVideo: hasVideo,
          completion: completion)
        }

}
```

Comment: I can't see how a background task scheduler is going to help you handle incoming calls; scheduled tasks will only run every hour or so. The exception says that you are trying to schedule the background task in an extension.  Do you have any extensions in your app? Are you calling this code from an extension?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you, Should i use notification center for listen incoming call from another user?

Comment: You would normally use PushKit/VoIP pushes along with callkit to ensure that your app can handle incoming calls even when it is terminated.